# Finding a closed form for a sum involving floor function $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\lfloor km/n\rfloor$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Given integers $m,n$, is there a known closed form for the sum
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk\lfloor km/n\rfloor$?
and if not, is it possible to show there is no closed form for this sum?
I've attempted to derive a closed form using the techniques in this question:
[Formula and proof for the sum of floor and ceiling numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207604/formula-and-proof-for-the-sum-of-floor-and-ceiling-numbers), with no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could help: If $m$  and $n$ are positive and coprime, then$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left\lfloor \frac{km}{n} \right\rfloor = \frac{1}{2}(m - 1)(n - 1)$$
[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Quotients)

Answer (score 2):

*This is only a partial answer*. There are three identifiable cases here: $m=n$, $m>n$, and $0<m<n$.

Case 1: $\textbf{m=n:}$ This is the simpler case:

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor\frac{km}{n}\rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor k\rfloor=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1),$$ by way of [Bernoulli's sum of powers formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Sum_of_powers). The other two cases are more difficult.

Case 2: $\textbf{m>n:}$ To simplify matters suppose $m=bn$ for some integer $b>1$. Then 
$$S=\sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor k\frac{bn}{n}\rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor k b\rfloor = b\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{b}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1).$$

For the more general case, suppose $m=bn+a$ with $1<a<n$ and $b\geq 1$. Then we have $$S=\sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor \frac{k(bn+a)}{n}\rfloor = \sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor kb+\frac{ka}{n}\rfloor = b\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+\sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor\frac{ka}{n}\rfloor,$$ so $$S= \frac{b}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)+\sum_{k=1}^n k\lfloor\frac{ka}{n}\rfloor,$$ where we see that $0<a/n<1$. **Thus the entire problem has been reduced to the third case only**, i.e. for when $0<m<n$ (see top of answer)

Case 3: $\textbf{0<m<n:}$ It may be the case that there is a closed form when $\text{gcd}(m,n)=1$.

Comment: Why does $m>n \rightarrow n\mid m$?

Comment: It doesn't, but for the special case $m=an$ we have $n\mid an$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following helps:

For given $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq1}$ put $\omega:=e^{2\pi i/n}$. Then for any integer $j$ one has 
$$\left\lfloor{j\over n}\right\rfloor={j\over n}-{n-1\over 2n}+{1\over n}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}{\omega^{j\ell}\over 1-\omega^{-\ell}}\ .$$

Comment: That's an interesting Identity, but I can't see how this helps.

Comment: Could you please provide a source/proof for this identity?

Comment: @SomeStrangeUser: I'm interested in a closed formula for the sum
$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1}k\lfloor \frac{km}{n}\rfloor$ too. Have you found any additional reference for it? Would you have any combinatorial interpretation for it?